# Swift dispatch_after throwing is not a prefix unary operator error

Tags: multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch

i have the following code:

```
import SpriteKit
import Foundation

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var occupiedCoordinates: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    func addShape () {

        //...

        shape.position = CGPoint(x:actualX, y:actualY)
        self.occupiedCoordinates.addObject(NSValue(CGPoint:shape.position))
        let halfDuration = random(min: CGFloat(0.5), max: CGFloat(5))

        //...

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2*halfDuration), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.occupiedCoordinates.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
            });
    }

}
```

i used the original snipped `GCD: Dispatch After` and i get the following message in the line of `dispatch_after()`

```
'^' is not a prefix unary operator
```

any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to pass a closure (i.e. an objective-c block) to a function in swift:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * halfDuration), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> () in
    self.occupiedCoordinates.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
})
```

or you can also use this compact form:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * halfDuration), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.occupiedCoordinates.removeObjectAtIndex(0)
}
```

Suggested reading: [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_152)

Comment: this yiels 
`cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type (dispatch_time_t, dispatch_queue_t!, 0)`

Comment: what's the type of `halfDuration`?

Comment: Ok - the function requires an Int64, and in swift there is no implicit conversion of data types. So you can either change the `halfDuration` type to Int64, or explicitly convert it in-place by using `2 * Int64(halfDuration)`

Comment: The second parameter of `dispatch_time()` is specified in *nanoseconds*. Assuming that `halfDuration` denotes seconds you have to multiply with `NSEC_PER_SEC`. And `Int64(halfDuration)` would truncate the fractional part, better something like `Int64(2 * halfDuration * CGFloat(NSEC_PER_SEC))`.

Answer (score 10):

`^{...}` is Objective-C syntax. You don't need the `^`.